# Cannot Get PushMagic from OS X 10.8.2 Device using MDM

Tags: macos, configuration, profile, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am trying to create my own MDM Server.  I can get an iOS device to enrole without a hitch, but when I install the same configuration profile (one that contains and mdm and credential payload) on an OS X 10.8.2 device, it does not send me its PushMagic.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?  What could cause the PushMagic to not get sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoke with apple, and you don't need PushMagic to send an APNS message to an OS X device!  Just put:

{"mdm":""}

in your payload

Comment: is this all you needed to do to get this to work? I'm running into a similar problem right now. How does the communication with the device (a Macbook Pro in this instance, for example) happen without the PushMagic? Kinda stumped on this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pardon the pun, but it's really by magic!  Apple support told me that it is missing in the documentation, and the next rev of the MDM doc will have this in it.